# Latitude and longitude change dynamically in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, dom-events, openlayers, angular-openlayers, gwt-openlayers

I am trying to point my address on a map in OpenLayers by using the code below :

```
var rome = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([12.5, 41.9]))
});

rome.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
        color: '#8959A8',
        crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
        src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.3.1/examples/data/dot.png'
    }))
}));

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [rome]
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource
});

var rasterLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileJSON({
        url: 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapbox.geography-class.json?secure',
        crossOrigin: ''
    })
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [rasterLayer, vectorLayer],
    target: document.getElementById('map'),
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([2.896372, 44.60240]),
        zoom: 3
    })
});
```

I have one input field `onchange` of that input field I will get the values of latitude and longitude.

I want to place those values on my point, so I have stored values I'm getting in global variable and accessing in my JS: `[longitude, latitude]`)
but it is not placing those values on map. but if i place values like `4.1111, 50.1111`, it works.

When I change my input values `[longitude, latitude]` changes but not apply on the below code :

```
var rome = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([longitude, latitude]))
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your function with creating new feature is executing without filled variables? The code was executed and change in variables **will not** refresh the feature properties. You need to run function in onchange event. If you are not using any JS framework (Angular, React, Vue etc.) take a look for a plain JS solution ith button on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wh5h05rf/1/).

HTML:

```
  <input id="x" type="number" step="0.0001" value="4.1111">
  <input id="y" type="number" step="0.0001" value="50.1111">
  <button id="button">Add point</button>
  <div id="map"></div>
```

JS:

```
  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 2
    })
  })

  document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function( event ) {
    var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById('x').value)
    var y = parseFloat(document.getElementById('y').value)
    var feature = new ol.Feature({
      geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([x, y], 'EPSG:4326',     
      'EPSG:3857'))
    })
    var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
      features: [feature]
    })
    var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: vectorSource,
    })
    map.addLayer(vectorLayer)
  }, false)
```